# Cloned image changing fixed div position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a popup larger image when a user clicks an image within a carousel. I have achieved this, but the image position varies depending on its position within the carousel. The CSS I have now is:

```
#carousel1{
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#popUp{ 
    display: none;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 580px !important;
    height: 350px !important;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The related HTML is:

```
<div id = "carousel1">
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="1.png" alt="1" title="Flag 1 Title" />
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="2.png" alt="2" title="Flag 2 Title" />
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="3.png" alt="3" title="Flag 3 Title" />
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="4.png" alt="4" title="Flag 4 Title" />
    <img class="cloudcarousel" src="5.png" alt="5" title="Flag 5 Title" />
</div>
<div id = "popUp"></div>
```

The related jQuery is:

```
this.imagePop = function () {
    if (options.imagePop !== 'no') {

        $(container).bind('click', this, function (event) {

            clearInterval(event.data.autoRotateTimer); // Stop auto rotation if mouse over.
            clearInterval(event.data.intervalLeft);
            clearInterval(event.data.intervalRight);
            var text = $(event.target).attr('alt');
            // If we have moved over a carousel item, then show the alt and title text.

            var $img = $(event.target);
            $('#popUp').html($img.clone().height(200).width(300)).add($('#overLay')).fadeIn();
            $('#popUp').add($('#overLay')).click(function () {
                $('#popUp').add($('#overLay')).fadeOut(function () {
                    $('#popUp').empty();
                });
            });
        });
    };
};
```

For a working example of the issue refer to: www.bingetech.com/carousel

Is it possible to center the popUp div in the middle of the screen with the cloned image?

Comment: Hope you noticed my edit, next time put in your question only what is relevant to answer it. useless lines of PHP or other stuff just add noise to your code, making it hard to follow. Keep in mind! :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the .clone() method. You could make sure you're only setting the popUp image properties as cloning the image will result in contacting the same values as the cloned target.

```
#popUp img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -175px;
  margin-left: -290px;
}
```

Note: make sure this is declared below the .cloudcarousel class in css

Comment: Added that code, still not placing the images center... I was also thinking it could be the clone() method, still not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Do u need the current main - logo image to be replaced by the one the user would be clicking in the carousel?

Can you elaborate more on the placement of the enlarged image. or a snapshot of what is desired?

Comment: exactly centered in the page, notice how the images pop up in different locations.

Comment: Try This. Place popup div before the carousel div. ANd change the styling of popup to `position:relative;margin:0px auto' and reduce the height of popup block to the image height i.e 200px